# get current user email in Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identity

I use `IIdentity` interface For Getting current `userid` and `username`.

so implement following Method:

```
private static IIdentity GetIdentity()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.User != null)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
    }

    return ClaimsPrincipal.Current != null ? ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity : null;
}
```

And Add this code: `_.For<IIdentity>().Use(() => GetIdentity());` in my IoC Container`[structuremap]`.

**Usage**

```
this._identity.GetUserId();
this._identity.GetUserName();
this._identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Now I Want to Implement `GetEmailAdress` Method, How To do this?

**Example**

```
this._identity.GetEmailAdress();
```

When use `this._identity.GetUserName();` do not get username form **database**.

Comment: The email is data from the user's profile, not his identity. You need to get the current user's profile object, then retrieve his email.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something on these lines:

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static string GetEmailAdress(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var userId = identity.GetUserId();
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
            return user.Email;
        }
    }        
}
```

and then you will be able to access it like:

```
this._identity.GetEmailAdress();
```

Comment: when use `this._identity.GetUserName();` do not get username from database.

Comment: Yeah, beacause Username is a part of your Principal, but not email. You would have to get email from the DB, unless you are using claims in your application. In which case you could set it in the claims when authenticating the user and later read it from claims.

Comment: Ok, you can show me how to do this or edit your answer,... ?

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh the answer already shows that. The *identity* of a user is *not* the same as his/her profile properties. You can't get the email from the identity, any more than one can get *your* email from your passport or driver's license. Some sites use an email address as the user name. They still allow you to change the *contact email* though, without changing your user name

Answer (score 5):

You can get the current user in `ASP.NET Identity` as shown below:

```
ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
    .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
    .FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

//If you use int instead of string for primary key, use this:
ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
    .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
    .FindById(Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()));
```

For getting custom properties from `AspNetUsers` table:

```
ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByName(userName);
string mail= user.Email;
```

Comment: thanks, @MuratYıldız I use `ASP.NET Identity` but I want to get EmailAdress like `this._identity.GetUserName();` that do not get it from database.

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh Could you try to update implemented method with the related lines on my answer? Maybe it fix the problem and you can achieve to use the implemented method successfully.

Comment: I think, can fix this problem with claims.

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh the user's name is one thing. The user's email is another. You can't get profile information from an identity, it's like asking to get one's email from his passport, identity card or driver's license. There's nothing to fix here - claims are *still* a form of identity. Besides, you can have one email address as your user name, and another as your contact email

Answer (score 0):

Home Controler

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult GetUserEmail()
        {
            try
            {
                var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                ViewBag.EmailData = db.AspNetUsers.Where(s => s.Id == userID).Select(x => x.Email).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
                return Content(ViewBag.EmailData);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

And in View

```
@{
string USREmail = Html.Action("GetUserEmail", "Home").ToString();
}
```

You Can Show Email

```
@USREmail
```