# ASP.NET MVC Controller to View Passing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I started learning ASP.NET and I am still not completely familiar with it. 
I need to pass Account Controller data to my home index view.
I am manipulating default authentication. I added a new column (Gender) into the ASPNETUSERS table using migration. I need to get the current login user details and show it into my `Index` view of `HomeController`.

I already filtered by using below code inside `AccountController`.

```
var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var x = UserManager.FindById(currentUserId);
ViewBag.Gender = x.Gender;
```

I think this code can be filtered particular column for the login userid.
Am i thinking wrong about these? if i am wrong please explain it.

The main problem which i am facing right now is to pass this `@ViewBag.Gender` to `Index` view. Is it possible to use `@ViewBag.Gender` in the `Index` view of `HomeController`?
My understanding is the `ViewBag` has to be defined inside the `HomeController` to pass `Index` view page of `HomeController`.

How can I pass `AccountController` data to `Index` view of `HomeController`?
I am not referring to use `ViewBag`. As long as it passes the value i am happy with that.
And please give me some suggestions to do this perfectly.

Comment: No you cannot pass data from one controller to another using `ViewBag` (although you could using `TempData`. You should be just using the code snippet above inside the `Index()` method of `HomeController`

Comment: Maybe you need persist the data into db or cache.

Comment: `ViewBag` used to pass controller data into view. You can use `TempData` or `Session` to pass between controllers instead. Also `@ViewBag.Gender` should be used in `HomeController.Index()` method.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, I also tried that, Actually the UserManager class is located inside the AccountController. So, that code can't work outside the AccountController. Can you prefer any different approach to get filtered data from the user table?

Comment: What do you mean it cant work outside `AccountController` (of course it can)

Comment: `UserManager` is an ASP.NET Identity class, right? It should be work for all controller classes if you reference the `Identity` namespace.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, It says "The name UserManager" does not exist in the current context". I found the source class is located in AccountController. I think it can't work outside unless any kind of references.

Comment: The I assume you have not included the necessary namespaces - e.g. `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;`

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto, I also tried to include "using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;". But still it is not working

Comment: Wait, Is the ActionResult method on your Account Controller returning a partial view by chance? If I am correct then even if you get the correct answer (which is to use TempData) then it's still not going to help you out.

Comment: @Travis Acton, No, I tried those code inside the view returning class, but i think it was no point to keep in there because I don't want to pass those data into those views. so i moved it into public AccountController(){}.

Comment: I do not mean this to be derogatory but  I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the MVC framework works. To get assistance with this issue I believe you should post your controller code for Account and Home and let people guide you on this one.

Comment: @Travis Acton, Maybe i understood the concept wrong, what i understood so far is that controller can be able to pass data to it's views and not to another controller's views. My question is to pass the value from one controller to different controller's view. did I understand anything wrong here?

Comment: What you need to wrap your head around is that controller methods do not have views. Views are just one of many things a controller method can return. Once a view is returned then it's basic visual state belongs client side. A Controller method can however issue a redirectToAction to send data to a different controller method or it could return any other specific view that is normally associated with other controller methods OR it could return a partialview OR it could return a jsonResult if you are calling the controller method via ajax. You need to post your controllers so people can help.

Comment: @Travis Acton, what you said was true, but what i am asking is not much of a bigger problem. I think you didn't understand my question or maybe the way of my question is wrong to be understood. Sorry for the trouble and I actually found the solution. Anyways thanks for your suggestion. I will keep it in my mind for my future problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer from another question area.
[get current user email in Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532765/get-current-user-email-in-identity)

```
ApplicationUser x = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
   .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
   .FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

ViewBag.Gender = x.Gender;
```

I can use this in my `HomeController`and pass the `ViewBag` to `Index`of the `HomeController`using `@ViewBag.Gender`

To work this code without any error I have to insert below using references

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using ProjectName.Models;
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Use TempData["gender"] in AccountController and redirect to HomeController.
In HomeController get that data in ViewBag and use it on View.